# Is this function integrable over the domain?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, piecewise-continuity

I'm doing this lua question (I know this is a math exchange) but my question is about integration and different methods for calculating this:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left | xsin\left ( \frac{1}{x} \right ) \right | dx,  x \neq 0$$ and $$0, x=0$$
I'm not too sure how to write the piecewise function here sorry.

And the programme I wrote dealt with this and I was wondering if there is a definite integral for this.

These are the options and I can't seem to understand which one it may be:

**This function is integrable, but it is difficult to find the order of either method. 

This function is not integrable in this region. 

It is impossible to calculate the integral because of run-time errors. 

This function is not continuous in this region. 

This function is not well-defined.**

My thoughts are the 2nd option - could someone help please, thank you!

Comment: It's a continuous positive function, obviously it is integrable.

Comment: @Crostul Appreciate it thanks mate

Comment: 1) Hard to tell, because you spared us "either method", 2) it *is* integrable, 3) depends on implementation, not a mathematical question, 4) it *is* continuous, 5) it *is* well defined.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You're a legend, have a great day